# Applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to variable `x` does not yield a constant expression in the code below. Why is that?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constant-expression

The snippet below was obtained from [DR 2083](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2083) by Hubert Tong.

```
extern int globx;
int main() {
    const int &x = globx;
    struct A {
        const int *foo() { return &x; }
    } a;
    return *a.foo();
}
```

Then the author writes:

> `x` satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression,
> but applying the lvalue-to-rvalue converstion to `x` does not yield a
> constant expression.

Why applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` does not yield a constant-expression?

Comment: The value of `globx`, and its memory address, are both not known until runtime. I see no "constant expression" or "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" in this code

Comment: @RemyLebeau I fail to see your point. `x` does satisfy requirements for appearing in constant expression, so what are you trying to say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` reads the value of the mutable global variable `globx`, which makes it not a constant expression as the value of `globx` is subject to change (and, even if it were `const`, there would be the issue of its value not being known at compile time). Of course, this is not surprising: no one would expect `int{x}` to be a constant expression. The DR points out that this fact should, nonetheless, not cause the odr-use of `x` and thus the code should be well-formed: since `x` has constant initialization, the compiler can just translate `&x` into `&globx`.

Comment: When you say "Applying the l-to-r conversion to `x` reads the value of the mutable global variable `globx`", I don't agree with that. Applying the l-to-r conversion to `x` reads the value of the variable `x`, not `globx`.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso I'm sorry, but that makes no sense whatsoever. The standard quite clearly says "the object indicated by the glvalue is read". References are not objects.

Comment: I think you're right because `x` is a reference, thus an l-to-r conversion applied to `x` reads the value of `globx`.

Comment: What do you mean by "no one would expect `int(x)` to be a constant expression"?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso I think it's clear to everyone that the value of `int{x}` is not a compile-time constant. Applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to `x` is basically computing `int{x}`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not familiar with this expression `int{x}`.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso please see [expr.type.conv] (C++20 §7.6.1.3) for explanation

Comment: Now I understand that int{x} is equivalent to int(x). Thanks.

Comment: There is still one thing that I'm missing: why applying the l-to-r conversion to `x` is basically computing `int{x}` ?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso In writing my answer, I assumed that the reader would be familiar with what `int{x}` does (to provide intuition for what happens during an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion). However, since you were not familiar with this syntax, I apologize for causing more confusion. Anyway, because `int{x}` also causes the value of `x` to be read, that's why it has the same effect as an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.